# AutoMapper Nested Mappings

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

So I have an interface, used for DI:

```
public interface IMapper<in TIn, out TOut>
{
    TOut Map(TIn objectToMap);
}
```

And a base class for my mappers:

```
public abstract class MapperBase<TIn, TOut> : IMapper<TIn, TOut>
{
    internal IConfigurationProvider MapperConfiguration { get; set; }

    public TOut Map(TIn objectToMap)
    {
        return MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<TOut>(objectToMap);
    }
}
```

And I'll use the following simplified data model ("same" for DAL and Service layers)

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Installation> Installations { get; set; }
}

public class Installation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following mappers between my DAL and Service layer:

```
public class DalClientToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Client, Interface.Model.Client>
{
    public DalClientToServiceMapper(IMapper<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract> contractMapper)
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DAL.Client, Interface.Model.Client>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract>().ConstructUsing(contractMapper.Map);
        });
    }
}

public class DalContractToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract>
{
    public DalContractToServiceMapper(IMapper<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation> dalInstallationToServiceMapper)
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation>().ConstructUsing(dalInstallationToServiceMapper.Map);
        });
    }
}

public class DalInstallationToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation>
{
    public DalInstallationToServiceMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation>();
        });
    }
}
```

But when I map a client, AutoMapper gives me an exception saying that there's no mapping defined for Installation (the nested-nested type).

When I configure a mapping for Installation in the Client Mapper it works fine.

What I don't understand is, I provide a specific method to map the nested type "Contract" from "Client", and a specific to map "Installation" from "Contract", so why is automapper trying to use his mapping configuration for the nested types of the nested types ? Why isn't he just stopping there and using the method I provided ? How can I achieve what I want to do here, chaining mappers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the profile.

I define all my mappings in a class that derives from profile:

```
public class DalToServiceProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<DAL.Client, Interface.Model.Client>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation>();
        CreateMap<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract>();
    }
}
```

I change my base class to looks like this:

```
public abstract class MapperBase<TIn, TOut, TProfile> : IMapper<TIn, TOut> where TProfile : Profile, new()
{
    internal IConfigurationProvider MapperConfiguration { get; set; }

    protected MapperBase()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<TProfile>();
        });
    }

    public TOut Map(TIn objectToMap)
    {
        return MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<TOut>(objectToMap);
    }
}
```

And my Mappers ar now simpler:

```
public class DalClientToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Client, Interface.Model.Client, DalToServiceProfile>
{
}

public class DalContractToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Contract, Interface.Model.Contract, DalToServiceProfile>
{
}

public class DalInstallationToServiceMapper : MapperBase<DAL.Installation, Interface.Model.Installation, DalToServiceProfile>
{
}
```

I need this extra layer as we're using dependency injection and need to inject the mappers based on their interface.

All my mappers know all the mapping configuration, but I don't see that as a big deal in my situation.

Also they are not chained, but as they each just load the same profile, they do the same stuff.

In fact all I do here is decoupling my mapper by using the IMapper interface, so I can easily inject my mappers and use them strongly typed. Cleaner then invoking everywhere in my services Mapper.Map or creating mapper in my service facades.